# Exclude Multiple OUs in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, where-clause

I need to figure out how to exclude multiple OUs from the below foreach loop by distinguished name so the user/computer account is not found twice (once in it's original OU and then again in the OU it's moved to.

I tried using a Where clause trying to filter a single OU for testing but when I run the script with it nothing below it processes.  What is the best method to exclude the OU(s) from my foreach loop?

```
foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    #Where($OU.DistinguishedName -ne 'OU=Disabled Users,DC=test,DC=local') {
        $params = @{
        SearchBase = [String]$OU.DistinguishedName
        SearchScope = [String]"OneLevel"
        AccountInactive = $true
        TimeSpan = ([timespan]$days)
        Verbose = $true
        }

        If($users) { 
            $params.Add("UsersOnly",$true)
        }
        ElseIf($computers) { 
            $params.Add("ComputersOnly",$true)
        }

        $accounts = Search-ADAccount @params

        $params.Clear()

        foreach($account in $accounts) {
            If ($noDisable -notcontains $account.Name -and $account.ObjectClass -eq "User" ) {
                $params = @{
                    Identity = [string]$account.DistinguishedName
                    Verbose = $true
                }
                Disable-ADAccount @params @whatIf

                $params.Add("Description",$description)

                Set-ADUser @params @WhatIf

                $params.Remove('Description')
                $params.Add("TargetPath", 'OU=Disabled Users,DC=test,DC=local')

                Move-ADObject @params @WhatIf
            }
            elseif($noDisable -notcontains $account.Name -and $account.ObjectClass -eq "Computer") {
                $params = @{
                    Identity = [string]$account.DistinguishedName
                    Verbose = $true
                }
                Disable-ADAccount @params @whatIf

                $params.Add("Description",$description)

                Set-ADComputer @params @WhatIf

                $params.Remove('Description')
                $params.Add("TargetPath", 'OU=Disabled Computers,DC=test,DC=local')

                Move-ADObject @params @WhatIf
            }   

        }
    #}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how where works.

```
Where(){} # Wont Work
```

You need to pipe to **Where-Object**

```
$OUs | Where-Object{$_.DistinguishedName -ne 'OU=Disabled Users,DC=test,DC=local'} | Foreach-Object{
    #Do Stuff Here
}
```

Example

```
$Names = @("Steve", "John", "Smith")
$Names | Where-Object{ $_ -ne "John"} | Foreach-Object{
    $_
}
```

That will return

```
Steve
Smith
```

Now you said you had many OUs to exclude so lets change it up a little to exclude multiple names.

```
$Names = @("Steve", "John", "Smith", "Billy", "Sally")
$ExcludeList = @("Steve", "Smith", "Sally")
$Names | Where-Object{ $ExcludeList -notcontains $_ } | Foreach-Object{
    $_
}
```

This will return

```
John
Billy
```

Comment: thank you so much for that awesome explanation.  I got it working!